# improvements on code

Tags: python, python-3.x

Enter a number with only two digits: 10

enter another integer: 1

1 is the reverse of: 10

**My Code**

```
from pcinput import getInteger


minimum_len = 2
number1 = getInteger("enter a number with only two digits: ")
input_length = int(len(str(number1)))

if input_length < minimum_len: 
    print("needs to be 2 digits" )
    exit(1)
elif not isinstance(number1, int):
    print("needs to be a int")

else: 
     number2 = input("enter another integer: ")

def reverse_int(number1):
    return int(str(number1)[::-1])

if number1 == number2:
    print(str(number1) + " is the reverse of "+ (str(number2 )))
else:
    print(str (number2) + " is not the reverse of " + (str(number1)))
```

Comment: you don't call your `reverse_int` anywhere

Comment: minimum length requirements are working. But you need to use `exit(1)` to exit from program if requirements is not satisfies to avoid the error following.

Comment: "the first number must have less than two digits " Are you sure about that? Don't you want the first number to have exactly 2 digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't call the `reverse_int` function anywhere.

```
- if number1 == number2:
+ if number1 == reverse_int(number2):
```

Comment: Wow, thank you I've been looking at my code for too long that I missed such an easy mistake.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand if you reverse 10 you will get 01. And in programming 01 is not a  number, so the number just equates to 1. If I were you I would also verify the length of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of turning the number to a string and finding the length of that, you could check the value of the number.  10 is the smallest two digit number and 99 is the largest.

You can similarly avoid strings when reversing the digits:

```
def reverse(number):
    tens = number // 10
    ones = number % 10
    return 10 * ones + tens
```

Then all you need to do is reverse one of the numbers:

```
if number2 == reverse(number1):
    print("{0} is the reverse of {1}".format(number2, number1))
```

Comment: I notice that if I put in a number like 4 it returns 40 which makes the if then else statement produces the wrong answer since 4 is the reverse of 4 @SpacedMonkey

Comment: if 1 is the reverse of 10 then 4 is the reverse of 40.  This is why the first number must have 2 digits and why I reverse that number.